# Tightness of a vector valued sequence of stochastic processes

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes

Let $\pmb{X}^{n}_{t}=\left(Y_{t}^{n},Z_{t}^{n}\right)$ be a sequence of a vector valued stochastic processes, where each component is cadlag.
In order to prove the tightness of $\pmb{X}_{t}^{n}$, is it sufficient to prove the tightness for each component separately?

Why?

What if $Y_{t}^{n}=Y_{t}$ for all $n$?

Comment: Tight in what space? If you mean the product of Skorokhod spaces (with the usual J1 topology), $D_{\mathbb{R}}[0,\infty)^2$, then yes. If you mean the Skorokhod space of the product (again, J1 topology), $D_{\mathbb{R}^2}[0,\infty)$, then no. Having one component be constant does not help if you mean the Skorokhod space of the product, but having one component be continuous does.

Comment: I mean the product of Skorohod spaces.